# Instruct Google Search to blacklist w3schools.com from search results

Tags: google-search, blacklist

Every time I Google for any CSS property, the first result is always on w3schools.com (a.k.a. the most useless, bogus and misleading site around).

Is there a way to add it to some sort of a black list, to get useful results first instead?

Comment: The *bogus and misleading sites* list is long and also includes `cplusplus.com`, `geeksforgeeks.org` and `wccftech.com` if you ask me.

Comment: @Marc.2377 i've usually found cplusplus.com somewhat useful, although it's a bit of a hit and miss; what do you suggest for C++ reference?

Comment: I find that [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) is to cplusplus.com as the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is to w3schools.com.

Answer (score 9):

#### Search parameter

One can exclude a site from search results with `-site:w3schools.com`. Compare searches for `inline block` and `inline block -site:w3schools.com`, for example.

To avoid typing this search parameter repeatedly, one can take advantage of  autocomplete: put the `-site` part first; then it'll come up again when you begin typing `-s`.

#### Client-side solution

Google offers a Chrome extension [Personal blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)  precisely for this purpose. The drawback is that this solution only works in Chrome.

#### Custom search engine.

Google offers [custom search engines](https://cse.google.com/) which support site exclusion. A drawback is that one has to specify the site(s) to search, and *.* isn't allowed. A workaround is to add popular top level domains, and set the search to be internet-wide, with only a preference for the site matching these (as shown below).

Google provides a URL for this custom engine, which you can bookmark and use instead of google.com

[image: cse]

Comment: Personal Blocklist seems to be abandoned, but you can use another wonderful extension called [Remove W3Schools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-w3schools/gohnadkcefpdhblajddfnhapimpdjkje) instead.